# Rectangle turns big after rotating in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

trying to rotate a rectangle in kivy, but come to a blindspot.
On the screen is a button, whenever clicked it rotates a rectangle, but when it rotates it also becomes a lot bigger. Why is this happening and how could i fix it? Also any tips for overall code will be appreciated.
Main file:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Rotate
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PushMatrix, PopMatrix
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Rect(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)


        self.angle = 0
        self.x, self.y = 500,500
        self.pos = self.x, self.y
        self.size = (50,100)
        
        with self.canvas:
            PushMatrix()
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            
            PopMatrix()
    
    def rotate(self):
        
        with self.canvas.before:
            self.canvas.clear()
            PushMatrix()
            Rotate(pos=self.pos, angle=0)
            Rectangle(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
            
            PopMatrix()


class MainScreen(Widget):
    rect = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
        
    def pressed(self):
        self.rect.rotate()



class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And kv file:

```
<MainScreen>:
    rect: rect
            
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        Rect:
            id: rect
        
        Button:
            angle: 0
            text: "press"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint: (.1,.1)
            on_press: root.pressed()
```

Comment: Since you are redrawing the Rectangle each time, I think when you first create it self.size is not the same as when the button is pressed - so the code does the same thing but since self.size is bigger later you see a larger Rectangle.

Comment: Oops, looks like self.size is already defined somewhere and on click changes to FloatLayouts size. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `size_hint` to `None, None` for the `size` values to have any effect. You can also simplify your code by using a `Property` for the `angle`. Here is a modified version of your `Rect` class:

```
class Rect(Widget):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.size_hint = (None, None)
        self.x, self.y = 500, 500
        self.pos = self.x, self.y
        self.size = (50, 100)

    def rotate(self):
        self.angle += 45
```

Then, your `kv` can look like:

```
<Rect>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            origin: self.center
            angle: self.angle
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
        
<MainScreen>:
    rect: rect
            
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        Rect:
            id: rect
        
        Button:
            angle: 0
            text: "press"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.1, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint: (.1,.1)
            on_press: root.pressed()
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, changing into kv file, moving stopped updating, how can do that?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I meant, after putting canvas into kv file, moving doesn't update it anymore.

Comment: I don't see any movement in your code, only rotation.